# Turn on Laptop backlight without a keyboard shortcut

Tags: laptop, display, backlight

I recently installed the latest drivers and my screen backlight turned off. The problem is that my `Fn-F7` key combination doesn't work, so I can't turn it back on.

I can see my screen at night if I hold a source of light next to the screen. So I can still do some trivial things with my laptop.

Is there a way to turn the backlight on without using `Fn-F7` key combination, either via the command line, or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt as administrator and enter:

> powercfg -restoredefaultschemes